# JTextArea in JScrollPane will not display

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane, jtextarea

i have been having a large problem with my GUI. my first problem was that when i press a button that causes my JTextArea to display a string, he text area changes and thus pushes around all of the buttons and everything else in my GUI. i tried many solutions but nothing worked.

I put my text area in a scroll panel which may or may not have worked. i dont know because no text is displaying in the scroll panel. can someone look at my code and tell me what i am doing wrong?

thanks

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class myClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    public JButton picture = new JButton();
    public JTextArea description = new JTextArea(10,30);
    public JButton B1 = new JButton();
    public JTextArea C1 = new JTextArea();

    public myClass (String STP){

        super(STP);
        makeGUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        myClass test = new myClass("story");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        Object source = event.getSource();
        if (source==B1){
            description.setText("hello world");
            C1.setText("hello world");
        }
    }

    public void makeGUI(){

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(description);
        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        Container con = this.getContentPane();
        setBounds(50,50,600,600); //(x,-y,w,h) from north west
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // picture
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.ipadx=260;
        gbc.ipady=310;
        gbc.insets=new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=0;
        gbc.gridwidth=2;
        gbc.gridheight=3;
        pane.add(picture,gbc);

        // button 1
        B1.addActionListener(this);
        gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.ipadx=0;
        gbc.ipady=10;
        gbc.insets=new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=3;
        gbc.gridwidth=1;
        gbc.gridheight=1;
        pane.add(B1,gbc);

        //caption 1
        gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.ipadx=0;
        gbc.ipady=30;
        gbc.insets=new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        gbc.gridx=1;
        gbc.gridy=3;
        gbc.gridwidth=3;
        gbc.gridheight=1;
        C1.setEditable(false);
        C1.setLineWrap(true);
        C1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        pane.add(C1,gbc);

        // description !this is the part im having a problem with!
        gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.ipadx=100;
        gbc.ipady=170;
        gbc.insets=new Insets(10,10,10,0);
        gbc.gridx=2;
        gbc.gridy=0;
        gbc.gridwidth=2;
        gbc.gridheight=1;
        description.setEditable(false);
        description.setLineWrap(true);
        description.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        scroll.add(description);
        pane.add(scroll,gbc);

        con.add(pane);

        setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

try pressing the small button in the bottom left corner. you should see text in both text areas, but only one works.

Comment: Why do you do this `new JScrollPane(description);` _and_ this `scroll.add(description);`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my table not visible when it's in a JScrollPane?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593867/why-is-my-table-not-visible-when-its-in-a-jscrollpane)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common mistake. So to elaborate the [solution by Reimeus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26406375/3182664) a bit:

The `JScollPane` is a complex component that contains several sub-components. It may contain the `Viewport` and possibly `JScrollBar`s, as shown in [this image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/figures/uiswing/components/scrollarchitecture.png) from the [How to use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) tutorial. These components are arranged with a special layout manager (particularly, with a `ScrollPaneLayout`).

When you just call `scrollPane.add(componentThatShouldBeScrolled)`, then the new component may replace one of existing components, or screw up the whole layout unpredictably.

Instead of manually adding the contents for the scrollpane, you usually pass it to the `JScollPane` constructor:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(componentThatShouldBeScrolled);
```

Alternatively, if you *have* to replace the "component that should be scrolled", you could call

```
scrollPane.setViewportView(componentThatShouldBeScrolled);
```

Answer (score 5):

Remove this statement which is replacing the `ViewPortView` of the `JScrollPane` component.

```
scroll.add(description);
```

The `JTextArea` `description` has already been set as the viewport view.